# How to count the bits in a Huffman tree

Tags: data-structures, huffman-code, huffman-tree

I am looking at the below Huffman tree, the corresponding frequency table and the subtotal table. That table calculates the subtotal bits. I want to know how to count the subtotal bits.

[image]

In the first row of the subtotal table, code 0 maps to 15. I understand that because A has a count of 15. But why code 100 maps to 21? 100 represents the node B and B has a count of 7. I would think that for 100 we should calculate 7 + 15 = 22, but the table has 21. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column "Subtotal (#bits)" is the product of bit-length and count (frequency), and this represents how many bits in the encoded message are dedicated to represent all symbols B.

So we can derive the numbers as follows:

| Symbol | Count | Code | #bits in Code | Subtotal (#bits) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 0 | 1 | 15 x 1 = 15 |
| B | 7 | 100 | 3 | 7 x 3 = 21 |
| C | 6 | 101 | 3 | 6 x 3 = 18 |
| D | 6 | 110 | 3 | 6 x 3 = 18 |
| E | 5 | 111 | 3 | 5 x 3 = 15 |
|  |  |  |  | TOTAL = 87 |

87 is thus the length of the encoded message.